# how do I sum some input fields value (plus multiply is value by an attribute representing price)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form where people enter quantities they want from a list of products. Each input value represent the amount they want and the attribute data-price stores the price of the product.

I am using this jquery code to sum put the fields values

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event
        $(".number.qty_input").each(function() {

            $(this).keyup(function(){
                calculateSum();
            });
        });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $(".number.qty_input").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
        $("#the_price_v_m").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
```

Now I need to customize it so that It allows me to multiply field value by attribute data-price each one of them has. I have already tried a few unsuccessfull methods and I wonder if I could get some help on this.

Thanks!

oh by the way the html I use is

```
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
```

Comment: You want to multiply the value entered into the `<input>` by the `data-price` attribute, and then sum the total?

Comment: sum += parseFloat(this.value)*parseFloat(this.getAttribute("data-price"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing without html, but I think you want to multiply each item in the loop by it's price, which is stored in a `data-*` attribute. So change this line:

```
sum += parseFloat(this.value);
```

to this:

```
sum += parseFloat(this.value * $(this).data('price'));
```

some additional parsing may be neccessary without knowing your code too well:

```
sum += parseFloat(this.value) * parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
```

FYI:

`.data('price')` will get you the attribute named `data-price` on a jQuery object.

Comment: DOM elements don't have `.data()` method. `this.dataset.price` or `$(this).data('price')` ?

Comment: hi, I updated it with my html thanks for your help. I tried to use it but it didn't returned any value. I am traying whaty @Vohuman said and see if it works. Thanks guys.

Comment: GUYS YOU ARE AMAZING!! Thanks for the help it worked!! I am not so good at javascript :/

Comment: thanks @vohuman, for some reason i was assuming the "this" returned within a jquery each was already jquerified.. :-) my bad, thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to  manually iterate over the jQuery object to attach event handlers, jQuery does it for you. You can use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method to access the value of data attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".number.qty_input").keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".number.qty_input").each(function() {
      var price = $(this).data("price")
        //add only if the value and price is a number
      if (this.value.length && !isNaN(this.value) && !isNaN(price))
        sum += parseFloat(this.value) * parseFloat(price);
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#the_price_v_m").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15">
<span id="the_price_v_m"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, is to use a

```js
// assign a keyup event-handler to each of the 'input.qty_input' elements:
$('input.qty_input').on('keyup', function(e) 
  // create a temporary variable (to avoid recreating a variable in the map():
  var tmp,
    // iterate over the .qty_input elements, using map()
    sum = $('.qty_input').map(function() {
      tmp = $(this);
      // returning the numeric result of the entered-value multiplied by the data-price:
      return (+tmp.val() * tmp.data('price')) || 0;
    // use get() to form an array:
    }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    // reducing the array to a single value, summing all the array-elements together:
      return a + b;
    });
  // assigning the sum to the '#result' element (or whatever you want to do):
  $('#result').text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15" />
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15" />
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15" />
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15" />
<input type="text" class="number qty_input valid" data-price="15" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - `Array.prototype.reduce()`.
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).